# What does MSMQ do? only storage or else store and send to another queue

Tags: msmq

Does MSMQ is an temporary storage location or else it will store and send messages to the someother queue also without help any other application.

Comment: My Understanding about MSMQ is, its a common storage (of course you can create many queues)and application can put message into it. Any other application or services can read it.                My Question here is  Can MSMQ can send a message (without help of any programming )to other MSMQ thats sitting on another computer or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSMQ is a network protocol. You need to write applications that make use of that protocol. There is no communication between MSMQ-enabled machines without human intervention through coding.

Comment: Then when to use MSMQ Routing?

Comment: Don't use it unless you have some complicated network. It's a hangover from the 90s when LANs were a patchwork of technologies.